# Copy column B to column A (sorta)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to figure out a safe way (if possible) to take the "url" column and copy it into the "company" column ... but I don't just want to copy the whole thing - let me try to explain.

I want to copy the company name like **for example**: apple, mircosoft..etc (from the path) and place them into their company column (to the left). I have about 5000+ results that need to be done and done safety. They all have the same file path structure with "../../images...."

Could I use something like UPDATE with SET?

```
UPDATE table SET company = url
```

[image]

Thanks for an feedback! I really appreciate it!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: As there is nothing in the company column you can write/test/rewrite/retest ..... a query as many time s as you like until you get it right. When you get it wrong just blank out the company column and start again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick out the N left-most "fields" in a string separated by a character of your choice.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 4)
FROM mytable
LIMIT 10;
```

Returns:

```
../../images/apple
etc.
```

Then use a -1 to get the right-most field of that result to get the last one.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 4), '/', -1)
FROM mytable
LIMIT 10;
```

Returns:

```
apple
```

Once you are happy with the expression, use it in an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE mytable SET company = 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 4), '/', -1);
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

In mysql 8 you can use the [regexp_substr](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) function to use a regular expression to find a substring. Something like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '[^/]+', 14) FROM table;
```

Which would find any character that is not a `/` but starting at character 14 (part right after your leading `../../...etc` string.